# Apps reading net drives is freezing them

Tags: networking, freeze, drive, nas

I've a NAS and its folders I need mounted automatically using `/etc/fstab` file.

Everything works like a cham, but when I use some GTK apps like Firefox and it tries to look for a folder, it seems the app looks into the NAS folders and it takes a lot of time, freezing the app. It happens the first time the net drives are accessed for the first time I boot.

Whay does it happen? How could I solve it? It's very annoying.

Thanks!

Comment: It maybe the NAS is saving power; turning itself into *standby* mode, and your system is waiting for it to respond to requests (whilst the NAS devices wakes itself & drives up.  once the NAS is woken up the issue is gone)  I've got some old NAS devices that did this; so I stopped having them auto-mount via `fstab` and just had an auto-run script that did the `mount` (& then made some enquiries of the NAS devices that caused them to wake up properly; ignoring the replies, the NAS devices were awake then when I accessed them)   *this may not be your issue, but it reminds me of mine*

Comment: I think that's not the problem. It happens even when I just have accessed to the NAS using the file browser :(